# changing selected date - year only - JS

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date let us say "17-2-1978" and i checked if it is in the past. While checking, if it is in the past, i want to change only the year to 2018. How can this be done?

code below:

```
function startCountDown(){
    var testing = document.getElementById("events-div").lastChild.textContent;
    alert(testing);    
    var selectedDate = new Date(testing);
    var now = new Date();
    if (selectedDate < now) {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getFullYear()+1;
        selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate + n);
        alert(selectedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: setFullYear() instead of setDate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setFullYear` method. Example:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2018);
```

To display it in the format you want you can use `getDate`, `getMonth` and `getYear`

```
var formatted = [d.getDate(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getYear()].join('-');
```

The month is zero-based, so you'll need to add 1 to it.

Comment: Thanks, after doing this i am getting the full date format, how to re-format the date to show only 17-2-2018 only without the time and time zone?

Comment: [*setYear*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.getyear) is not deprecated, though its use is discouraged.

Comment: Ah, it is deprecated in Firefox.

Comment: I don't get any error messages using *setYear* in Firefox 56, any browser that doesn't support *getYear* is not compliant with any version of ECMA-262.

Comment: I'm just referring to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear

Comment: MDN is a public wiki not official Mozilla documentation, so your milage may vary… ;-) The comment on lack of support should reference non–browser hosts, browsers are still required to support it.

Answer (score 1):

First the date string needs to be correctly parsed to construct the date object:

```
var from = testing.split("-");
var d = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
var today = new Date();
if (d < today) {
    d.setFullYear(2018);
} else {
    //date is in future so no change
}
```

**See example below:**

```js
var testing="17-2-1978";
var from = testing.split("-");
var d = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
var today = new Date();
if (d < today) {
    d.setFullYear(2018);
} else {
    //date is in future so no change
}
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=d;
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: Parsing using the built–in parser is not recommended, especially for [*non–standard format strings*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). In Safari, `new Date('17-2-1978')` returns an invalid date (or `NaN` when using *Date.parse*).

Comment: @RobG Updated answer addresses your issue